FontAwesome Brands scss files generating square character instead of unicode value in css
I am working with a plain html, js, and scss template for a website. The template uses gulp to build the scss into css. I'm looking to incorporate fontawesome brand icons into my website. I downloaded the fontawesome package for version 6 onto my computer. I copied the _variables.scss, _functions.scss, and brand.scss into my app so it can be apart of the build process.
The brand.scss imports the variables and functions scss files. In the variables file, a variable is defined:
$fa-var-monero: \f3d0;
$fa-brand-icons: (
  "monero": $fa-var-monero,
   ...
);

The brands.scss file iterates over the $fa-brand-icons variable:
@each $name, $icon, $test in $fa-brand-icons {
  .#{$fa-css-prefix}-#{$name}:before { content: unquote("\"#{ $icon }\""); }
}

The css that gets built doesn't have the unicode value for the content style. It has a square character that looks like an error as shown below:
.fa-sourcetree:before{content:}

I noticed that even when I manually write a test value I get the same error character:
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-#{$name}:before {content: unquote("\f3d0"); }

This creates the same error character as listed above.
How can I fix the scss file so that the proper characters get printed in the css that is built?
